# Can't read json RESTful response in angularJs

Tags: json, angularjs

How can I read "teams" array in this json response in angularjs?

```
 {
  "_links" : {
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/teams/search"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "teams" : [ {
      "name" : "Perspolis",
      "location" : "Tehran",
      "mascotte" : null,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/teams/1"
        },
        "players" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/teams/1/players"
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

I used in html page in angularjs controller(link is working correctly in browser):

```
 $http.get("http://localhost:8080/teams").success(function (response)   {$scope.names = response._embedded.teams;});
```

But it doesn't load teams array data ! Would you mind helping me?

Comment: Is the callback even called? What's the content of `response`?

Comment: `console.log(response);` to see what in there...

Comment: log response to check if you get it, the request might be blocked. Check you network traffic

Comment: the last code is angularjs, it is not server side.

Comment: Your browser has a console as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your response data is inside `response.data`. `response` stores other request related information as well, like the returned status code.